# AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient() java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, android, android-studio

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.msgqueue3/com.example.msgqueue3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.CreateQueueResult com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS.createQueue(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.CreateQueueRequest)' on a null object reference

AWS SQS connection problem

Comment: [What is NullPointerException and how to fix it?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510)

Comment: thank you. AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient(); not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the AWS Java SDK ***V2***. It will allow you to use an alternate HTTP runtime, and avoid some of the mess with the Apache client, when working on Android.

[GitHub Issue #1180](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1180) in the AWS Java SDK V2 repo addresses this topic.

Specifically, in your module-level `build.gradle`, add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sqs:2.13.49'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.13.49'
}
```

Now, initialize the SQS client:

```kotlin
val sqs = SqsClient.builder()
    .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.create())
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    .credentialsProvider(yourCredentialsHere())
    .build()
```

Answer (score -1):

its working.

```
     ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();

    try {

        credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);

    }
    AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
            .build();
```